# MongoDB query on node.js express becomes very slow under load testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mongodb, express

I started doing some load testing on my node.js/express web app running a mongodb. I have a particular page that is loaded by hitting an end point like this:

```
app.get("/project/:pid", function(req, res) {
// project.viewProject(db, req, res);
project.viewProjectSimple(db, req, res);
});
```

This in turn calls a function which will show the project page associated with the pid. I have simplified this as much as possible to include only a single db query but the function still collapses under even a minor stress test.

Here is the function that renders the project:

```
exports.viewProjectSimple = function(db, req, res) {
console.time("project");
var pid = req.params["pid"]*1;
console.time("1");
db.collection("projects").findOne({pid:pid}, function(err, project) {
    console.timeEnd("1");
    if( !project )
        res.send("No such project...");
    else {
        console.time("2");
        project.user = {};
        project.user.name = "test";
        if( project.created )
            project.niceCreatedDate = utility.niceDate(project.created);
        if( project.totalTime )
            project.niceEditTime = utility.niceTimeDelta(project.totalTime);
        console.timeEnd("2");
        console.time("3");
        if( !project.stats )
            project.stats = getProjectStats(db, project);
        var uid = req.user ? req.user.uid : -1;
        if( project.description )
            project.descriptionHTML = markdown.toHTML( project.description, 'Gruber' );
        console.timeEnd("3");
        var renderProject = function() {
            console.time("4");
            var projectPath =  "public" + project.path;
            var screenshotPath = projectPath + "/info/screenshot.png";
            console.timeEnd("4");
            console.timeEnd("project");
            res.render("project", {
                title: "Project: "+project.name,
                user: req.user,
                customScript: "projectPage.js",
                scripts: ['/js/bootstrap.min.js', '/js/bootbox.min.js'],
                stylesheets: [ '/js/bootstrap.min.css'],
                permissions: getPermissionsHelper(req, project),
                project:project,
                message: req.flash("project")
            });             
        }
            renderProject();        
    }
}); 
}
```

When running with a single user the db query takes 10-15 seconds, here is the output from the timing calls:

```
1: 11ms
2: 0ms
3: 0ms
4: 0ms
project: 12ms
```

I have been running a blaze meter stress test that hits the project page over and over with 20 simulated users and when it peaks at 20 users the performance collapses and it takes about 15 seconds to complete the query:

```
1: 14145ms
2: 0ms
3: 1ms
4: 0ms
project: 14147ms
```

The projects table only has 31570 entries so I don't think that is the issue. This is currently running on a single amazon ec2 micro server with a single core and it maxes out the cpu during this test.

Can anyone enlighten me about what is going on here.

Comment: Is the field being queried indexed? If not then it probably should be as you are only looking up single values, and moreover if that is the case then why not use the `_id` field if it's just a single result? You should also look a the query performance on the server itself as this does not determine whether it's the query action or the node application that is the bottleneck here. Increase connection pool sizes and check memory utilization of the app. In short, there are many causes to look into beyond this simple test.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The field was not indexed and doing so did help significantly, now the query takes between 3000-7000ms during the max of the 20 user load test. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by looking at the query performance on the server, I am running these tests on an amazon instance that is an exact copy of the live server. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Monitoring the server means the actual `mongod` instance itself where more information can be [found in the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/). I'm mostly talking about the difference between your program issuing a query and the actual time of execution, as there is network latency to condsider as well. You might also consider that the instance used ( for both app and possibly database ) is under spec for the usage you want.